# Could I have the correct qmake, but the wrong qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I have a Qt5 code that was compiled with cmake, with no problems. Then I decided to try qmake and ran into a problem.

It looks like qmake is somehow using Qt4 instead of Qt5, even though *I think* it is configured to run Qt5. The code contains some strictly Qt5 elements.
Here is what I get from the terminal:

First, I have both Qt4 and Qt5:

```
wave@wave-T61:~$ qtchooser -l
4
5
default
qt4-i386-linux-gnu
qt4-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt4
qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt5
```

Show qmake version:

```
wave@wave-T61:~$ qmake -v
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.4.2 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

I can switch back and forth by setting:

```
wave@wave-T61:~$ export QT_SELECT=qt4
wave@wave-T61:~$ qmake -v
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.6 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

wave@wave-T61:~$ export QT_SELECT=qt5
wave@wave-T61:~$ qmake -v
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.4.2 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

However, regardless of qmake version I set I always get the Qt4 look, completely different from what I am getting with cmake (which looks as it should).

What am I doing, or assuming, wrong?

Thanks and sorry for a long-winded post.

EDIT.

Well, I have two Qt5 library source folders... cmake is configured to look at the place where I installed Qt5 - /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/ - and that is fine. 
But then I installed qmake and QCreator and, suddenly, there is another one, which is where qmake is looking - in /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/ .

Now, why this is so and why the second set of Qt5 libraries work as Qt4 is beyond me. Hopefully, I can redirect qmake and make it usable.

EDIT 2. Looks like I am out of luck, going back to cmake. From Qt documentation:

QT_INSTALL_PREFIX - Where the version of Qt this qmake is built for resides.
These built-in properties cannot have a version prefixed to them as they are not versioned, and each version of qmake will have its own built-in set of these values.

Comment: Do you create another build tree when you reset QT_SELECT variable? like this: `cd build && rm -r * && qmake .. && make` Also you can try to run `make VERBOSE=1` to see what is linked exactly.

Comment: Yes, I do everything from scratch. When compiled with qmake V.3 (Qt5), the Makefile doesn't mention qt4 at all, only qt5.
I guess I should compare the makefiles from qmake and cmake and see what is different.

Comment: Vitallii, VERBOSE=1 made me look a bit harder and I think I found the culprit, though I can't explain the whole behavior. I edited my post above. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Do you have the `qmake` executable inside your `/opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/` prefix? You can try to configure QtCreator to use this version, like in this guide http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake.html

Comment: Yes!!! Yes, I do! It is in /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/bin and I just ran that one and I am getting Qt5. Thanks Vitalii. My reputation doesn't allow me to vote you up or do anything else, don't know if somebody else could do it instead.

Comment: @wavelike You need not feel bad about this. If Vitalii Minnakhmetov posts an answer, you can *accept* it at any reputation level. Otherwise, you can either answer your own question (if you think it will be useful to others) or we might remove it as non-reproducible. Please *do not* edit the answer into the question itself or add `[SOLVED]` to the title.

Comment: Oops. Sorry for editing the title, I didn't know it was wrong as there is nothing about it in the help pages (as far as I see).
Also, I thought that Vitalii has posted answers but now see that those are "comments" so I guess there is no answer I can accept. Is there any reason I should answer my own question, seeing as I have put all explanations in my edited post? As far as I am concerned, the problem is solved.

Comment: "*Is there any reason I should answer my own question, seeing as I have put all explanations in my edited post?*" Yes, there is. The way to indicate that a question on this site has been answered is to accept an answer. It causes it to be marked as answered in the index page. I encourage @VitaliiMinnakhmetov to post an answer, which you can then accept. If he doesn't, feel free to post an answer yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select specific Qt version when building a qmake project in QtCreator, you need to add desired Qt version as described in [QtCreator documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake.html)